# CSS: responsive img size in div

Tags: image, css, responsive-design

I've an "info-section" (a `div`) where on the left should be a picture with `100% height` of the `div` and `50% width` of the `div`. The problem is, that the picture might be scaling too high and gets "unclear". So how could I solve this problem and still have a "high quality" image?

I tried it like that:

```
.preview-news-post:first-child {
    margin-top: 5%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 350px;
}



.preview-news-post:first-child img {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;

}
```

So `preview-news-post` is the `div` with a `width` of 100% ( because of a div wrapper, that 100% are equal 1600px )

Answer (score 1):

use a `max-width` or `max-height` setting that you set to the original width/height of the image. Also, I wouldn't force the image to be 50% of the header - this will in most cases distort the iamge and display it with a wrong heigth/width proportion. Instead, you can use `auto` for width, which will keep the original proportion in relation to the (flexible) height:

```
.preview-news-post:first-child img {
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 240px;
    width: auto;
}
```

(or the other way round: 50% width plus a max-width and height auto)